# how to get correct file when I wrap a logger in go?

Tags: go

I use a global logger like this:

```
[root@dev log]# cat src/logging/logging.go 
package logging

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var Logger *log.Logger

func init() {
    Logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "[Debug]", log.Llongfile|log.LstdFlags)
}

func Debug(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    Logger.SetPrefix("[Debug] ")
    Logger.Printf(format, v...)
}

[root@dev log]# cat src/main/main.go 
package main

import "logging"

func main() {
    logging.Debug("in main")
}
```

Here in main function I want to get:

```
[Debug] 2015/12/10 22:20:23 /tmp/log/src/main/main.go:6: in main
```

But I get following output instead:

```
[Debug] 2015/12/10 22:20:23 /tmp/log/src/logging/logging.go:16: in main
```

How can I get the correct file which calling the logger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `logger.Printf`, you need to use the raw `logger.Output` function, and provide the correct `callDepth` for the call point (the default is 2).

If you look at the code for [`Logger.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.Printf), you can see how it's done by default:

```
func (l *Logger) Printf(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    l.Output(2, fmt.Sprintf(format, v...))
}
```